# How to create an Apple ID?

Tags: mac, apple-id

I rebought my work MacBook Air and want to create a new Apple ID. Unfortunately, it is not working.

On the page where I have to add my credit card information (I choose "None"), the system is asking me for the "phone number area code". First, there is no phone number area code, and more importantly **there is no box to enter such a code**.

So simple question: How do I create an AppleID?

[image]

Comment: I tried to reactivate an old apple ID  but the password reset does not work. Ask me for some strange password I do not have

Comment: What happens if you create the Apple ID directly on appleid.apple.com and use this one to set up your Mac?

Comment: Yes finally! That seem to have worked! There was the same popup like the one I shows but this time with an actual box to enter my phone number! And after I created the account, added more details, signed in and signed in again, typing 5 times a code I received by phone, it seems I have been logged in!! WOW. Apple does finally work! After 1 hour of trying!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it doesn't work during the setup process of your Mac, you can also go to https://appleid.apple.com, create a new AppleID there and then use it during the setup of the Mac.